# Почему в тернарных вложенных операторах if else неожиданный результат?

Tags: php, тернарный-оператор

```
$i = 18; echo $i==17 ? "17" : $i==18 ? "18" : $i==19 ? "19" : "error";
```

Почему этот код выводит 19, а не 18?

`$i = 18; echo $i==17 ? "17" : $i==18 ? "18" : $i==19` - эта часть кода выводит 18.
Но когда добавляется `? "19" : "error";`- результат меняется на 19, но ведь по по по порядку этот участок уже находится в части условия else?

Comment: насколько понимаю, там ассоциативность ненмого веселая `( ( ($i == 17 ? "17" : $i == 18) ? "18" : $i == 19 ) ? "19" : "error" )`

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4):

Дело в том, что тернарный оператор читается слева направо, Вам верно ответили в комментарии.

```
$i = 18;
echo (($i==17 ? "17" : $i==18) ? "18" : $i==19) ? "19" : "error";
```

Вычисляется выражение в скобках и подставляется как значение в следующее и т.д.

Вот Вам более наглядный ответ на почему.

```
$i = 18;
echo $i==17 ? "17" : $i==18 ? "18" : $i==19 ? "19" : "error";
echo $i==18 ? "18" : $i==19 ? "19" : "error";
echo "18" ? "19" : "error";
```

Как видите строка "18" равна true потому на печать идет 19.

Answer (score 3):

Расставляйте скобки там, где последовательность выполнения не может быть точно определена, тогда Вы не будете себя вводить в заблуждения:

```
$i = 18; 
echo $i==17 ? "17" : ($i==18 ? "18" : ($i==19 ? "19" : "error"));
```

Это пример работающего запроса, последовательность выполнения которого как раз определяется расстановленными скобками, что не заставляет задумываться и задавать вопросы: "а какой же оператор будет выполнен раньше".

Comment: не корректно Вы скобки расставили ((

Comment: @WitalijKaa, Вы уверены? Проверьте внимательно =) На всякий случай, уточняю, что я не пытался описать как работает тернарный оператор, а всего лишь дал пример, как надо было это реализовать.

Comment: абсолютно уверен. пруф. http://php.net/manual/ru/language.operators.comparison.php Пример #4 Неочевидное поведение тернарного оператора

Comment: тернарные операторы вычисляются слева направо. а Вы расставили скобки в как бы обратном порядке

Comment: Я же говорю, что я не пытался объяснить, как работает тернарный оператор. Я привел пример, как правильно расставить скобки, чтобы результат соответствовал ожидаемой логике.

Comment: ну а человек спрашивал ПОЧЕМУ все работает так как работает. не о какой правильной логике в его вопросе не шло. и что по вашему правильная логика? в php тернарный оператор читается СЛЕВА НАПРАВО, это и есть правильная логика.

Comment: Отвечу на Ваш вопрос и предлагаю далее не вступать в дебаты =) Да, я действительно не ответил непосредственно на вопрос ПОЧЕМУ, тут Вы правы (но я и не писал, что я даю объяснение причины). Но говоря о правильной логике тут же очевидно, что топикстартер предполагает, что логика выполнения аналогична: `if (i = 17) {} else if (i == 18) {} else if (i == 19) {}`. И я дал рекомендацию, как исключить подобную неопределенность и реализовать в соответствии с ожидаемой логикой.

Comment: Абсолютно корректный ответ. Если читать его полностью, а не глянуть в код и домысливать за автора.

Comment: @Nikolay Автора вопроса как раз интересует собственное поведение оператора, а не то поведение, которые вы определяете с помощью расстановки скобок. Так что это не является ответом на вопрос.